# React Loader called twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here in my code the api is called twice,i see loading data twice in console ,

i tried a few ways like using a varibale to check if loader is already loaded etc,but none of them worked,i am beginner in react so not quite sure how tom fix this i also tried ai platforms but they failed too or gave responses which make the code even worse.so i am hoping i can get help here

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLoaderData, defer, Await } from 'react-router-dom';

//other imports

export const Loader = () => {
    let fetch_data = fetchRequest('', 'GET');
    console.log("loading data");
    return defer({ loaderPromise: fetch_data });
};

export default function Home() {

    const loaderData = useLoaderData();

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <React.Suspense fallback={<PreLoader />}>

                <Await resolve={loaderData.loaderPromise}>
                    {(resolvedData) => {

                        if (resolvedData.type === "warning") {
                            throw new Error(resolvedData.msg);
                        }

                        let { coins_list, wallets_list } = resolvedData;

                        return (
                            <>
                               "JSX"
                               </>
                </Await>
            </React.Suspense>


            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my App.js where i defined Routes

```
import React from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements, RouterProvider, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home, { Loader as HomeLoader } from "./Pages/Home";

//Components
import Error from './Components/Error';

const App = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" errorElement={<Error />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} loader={HomeLoader} />
      </Route>
    )
  );
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}>

    </RouterProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I thought maybe this might be due to rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component but I wasn't able to reproduce any double-calling of a route loader this way with the information you have provided. Please [edit] to clarify what the exact problem is, including exact reproduction steps. See [mcve].

Comment: I don't have any thing different from what I posted,i think you can reproduce by copy pasting the above code,And i read on the internet that modifying the React.StrictMode should be last thing one should do.So I am hoping for a better answer from you.Thank you

Comment: I did copy your code, and I was unable to reproduce any double loader calls. See if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/live/ddd45d2d-1489-46e2-a9bf-d309b5678cf7 here is link to similar code please check it

Comment: This "double call" appears to be the `React.StrictMode` component. It's a non-production build tool that is intended to help you find bugs in your code and is basically expected behavior. Production builds should only mount components once, so the route and loader should also only be called once.

Comment: So is this fine to Remove "React.StrictMode" and use it for production ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend removing the `StrictMode` component, it serves a very useful purpose.

Comment: Ok then how shall i fix this ? Please help

Comment: There's nothing to fix. This is what the `StrictMode` component does and how it functions.

Comment: I cannot double my api calls to server it would not be wise to waste my server resources,as i am willing to use this for Production Purposes.

Comment: If "extra" API calls are a problem in your development environment then an option may be to rate-limit or mock the `fetchRequest` function in your non-production builds.

Comment: Same problem for this https://farazrouter.netlify.app/vans as well the loader is called for twice this is a build i deployed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you're facing is due to the loader being called twice. This could be because the loader is invoked both as a component (Loader) and within the route definition (loader={HomeLoader}). To resolve this, you should only use one method to load your data.

Since you're using react-router-dom, you can remove the Loader component and handle data loading directly within the route definition using the loader property.

Try this in app.js

```
const App = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" errorElement={<Error />}>
        {/* Remove loader property */}
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
      </Route>
    )
  );
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}
```

And then, in your Home component, you can fetch data directly using `useLoaderData` hook:

Comment: I don't get it as per react router docs a function has to be passed to loader prop,in my home.js file I am just defining the loader function and exporting it so that I can import it in app.js and pass as prop to Route.The loader function will not be called if I implement your approach, looking for reply or a better answer.Thank you

Comment: ***Where*** are you seeing the loader function being used as a React component? Your explanation doesn't make any sense. You also removed the route loader which is ***surely*** not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed, the `React.StrictMode` was interfering twice with the router as I defined it inside my `App()` function.

I just moved it outside the `App()` and it's fixed

Previously:

```
        const App = () => {
      const router = createBrowserRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
          <Route path="/" errorElement={<Error />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} loader={HomeLoader} />
          </Route>
        )
      );
      return (
        <RouterProvider router={router}>
    
        </RouterProvider>
      );
    }
```

Fix: defining router outside App()

```
    const router = createBrowserRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
          <Route path="/" errorElement={<Error />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} loader={HomeLoader} />
          </Route>
        )
      );
    
     const App = () => {
      
      return (
        <RouterProvider router={router}>
    
        </RouterProvider>
      );
    }
```